# PySpark generating combinations of values for each row

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am tring to get the combinations for each row of a dataframe. For example, my input data looks  like,

```
+-------+---+
|kc_pair|h_v|
+-------+---+
| [a, 1]|123|
+-------+---+
| [b, 2]|123|
+-------+---+
| [c, 3]|123|
+-------+---+
| [b, 2]|234|
+-------+---+
| [c, 3]|234|
+-------+---+
```

The output combination dataframe should be grouped by the h_v column and it should be like,

```
+---------------+---+
|       kc_pairs|h_v|
+---------------+---+
| [a, 1], [b, 2]|123|
+---------------+---+
| [a, 1], [c, 3]|123|
+---------------+---+
| [b, 2], [c, 3]|123|
+---------------+---+
| [b, 2], [c, 3]|234|
+---------------+---+
```

I've tried using itertools.combinations as a udf applied to the specific column. First aggregating the kc_pair with the same h_v value as a list, something like this,

```
+----------------------+---+
|              kc_pairs|h_v|
+----------------------+---+
| [a, 1], [b, 2], [c,3]|123|
+----------------------+---+
|        [b, 2], [c, 3]|234|
+----------------------+---+
```

And then applied the udf to column kc_pair

```
F.udf(lambda x: list(itertools.combinations(x, 2)),
                     returnType=ArrayType(ArrayType(StringType())))
```

Now, a critical issue is that it cannot avoid **data skew** which means if a cell in kc_pair contains over 10,000 elements, the worker might fail the task. Any idea to this problem?

Comment: About data skew, read this [article](https://itnext.io/handling-data-skew-in-apache-spark-9f56343e58e8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved using self join based on [mck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65495333/6080276) answer:

**UPDATE**: A straightforward solution

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark import Row
from pyspark.shell import spark
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

df: DataFrame = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(kc_pair=['a', 1], h_v=123),
    Row(kc_pair=['b', 2], h_v=123),
    Row(kc_pair=['c', 3], h_v=123),
    Row(kc_pair=['b', 2], h_v=234),
    Row(kc_pair=['c', 3], h_v=234),
])

df_final = df.alias('l').join(df.alias('r'), on=((f.col('l.h_v') == f.col('r.h_v')) &
                                                 (f.col('l.kc_pair')[0] < f.col('r.kc_pair')[0])))

df_final = df_final.select(f.array(f.col('l.kc_pair'),
                                   f.col('r.kc_pair')).alias('kc_pairs'),
                           f.col('l.h_v'))

df_final.show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+----------------+---+
|kc_pairs        |h_v|
+----------------+---+
|[[a, 1], [b, 2]]|123|
|[[a, 1], [c, 3]]|123|
|[[b, 2], [c, 3]]|123|
|[[b, 2], [c, 3]]|234|
+----------------+---+
```

Comment: Nice thought! Not tried yet but seems totally fine with my problem. About the data skew, I have read the link you commented above. Based on your self-join solution, `df.alias('l').join(broadcast(df.alias('r')), ...` is supposed to work here, isn't it?

Comment: Being honest, I'm not sure about it. Only testing with your real dataset and monitoring to know